# How do you edit your other profiles in TweetDeck?

Tags: twitter

How do you edit your other profiles in TweetDeck?

I click to Accounts. It shows all profiles I can tweet from. I select one (that is not my main Twitter account). I click "Edit your profile" and it launches twitter.com in edit mode on my main Twitter account, the wrong profile.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's not possible; instead you have to log into twitter.com and do it from there.